# Shipping restrictions based on groups of products

Tags: shipping

I’m building a website where a customer can customize and order a shed that will be delivered to their home.  The client has restrictions based on delivery:

**A. There is a 30 mile free delivery range from their shop.**

1. For sheds not exceeding 13’ at roof edge, it will be $2.75 per loaded mile after 30 miles.
2. For another set of sheds it will be $4.50 per loaded mile after 30 miles.
3. For another set, $5.75 per loaded mile after 30 miles.
4. For another set, $7.75 per loaded mile after 30 miles.

**B. Also, the customer is responsible for an “escort” in 2 states (MD & WV):**

1. MD permits up to 10’ wide - $30
2. MD permits over 10’ wide - $55
3. WV permits all buildings - $30

I need to know if their are currently any extensions that could handle both A & B.  If not, at least A.

Thank You,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are extensions.  Look for Amasty shipping restrictions, shipping rules, and shipping table rates.  You can even use all 3 together.   We use both table rates and restriction extensions on our production and works perfect.

https://amasty.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=shipping

Comment: Any other options? Amnasty said they cant handle my requests.

Comment: How are you determining their distance?  Your wanting a module to do that part?

Comment: I would have a starting point for the shed shop.  Then it would need to calculate based on the customer's address or delivery spot.  I would need several calculations based on which shed they pick.

Comment: Look into webshopapps.  They have more advanced shipping modules. It's all they specialize in

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of off-the-shelf extension to do a), its usually done by declaring zipcodes that make up the 30 mile radius (in which case it is covered). We have worked on custom extns do this this functionality using geo-location on the destination address, but just haven't released as a general extn as its pretty specific to the use case

B) is covered in a variety of extns on the market.